# Windows username without using Activex Control

Tags: javascript, activex, windows-authentication, activexobject

I am developing an internal site which should take the username from windows. I am doing currently this using ActiveX control. But I would like to hear if any other potential option available to do the same thing. Because activeX control not work on Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are certain ways to do this.

1. force IE to use activex
2. use a java applet with system access
3. use a browser plugin with system access

sadly there are no other ways. srsly.

Comment: No man there is got one :) :D...
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html
check this out

Comment: you asked for the windows username. what you linked here will just prompt you for your username and password in case you do not use IE.

Comment: were i work, we use ntlm combined with our active directory so unless you have an active directory you could spoof what ever login name you want.